# Repeated `merge branch master` commits in PRs - how to remove?

Tags: git, merge, branch

I have an embarrassing `git` issue that I'd like some assistance with.  To say that I'm not a `git` expert, is a painful understatement.

When I submit a pull request, my requests will typically have several commits as shown below .  This seems to be happening when I commit to a feature branch.  Can anyone shed some light on what may be happening here and how I might resolve it?  I'd be grateful for any assistance.  Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I think we need some more information. What git commands are you using when this happens? Anyway we can get a view of the git flow also? Are other people using this repo as well? Are you using `master` as your branch too?

Comment: There's nothing actually *wrong* with this. But if you dislike having a lot of merge commits, you probably want to set up a "rebase" oriented workflow rather than a "merge" oriented workflow. This has advantages (chiefly the lack of merges) and disadvantages (chiefly the lack of merges). The fact that you're using GitHub (Pull Requests are specific to GitHub) throws in some potential extra wrinkles, so you'll need to say a bit more here, but you should start by reading up on Git basics.

Comment: Thanks very much to the both of you for your help. Would you mind going into the "extra wrinkles" you mentioned in a bit more detail?  I'm working with a team and would like to clean up all of the merge messages.  For some reason I'm not up-to-date on, I'm the only one in the team who has them.  Thanks in advance.